How Do I Print an Equation Using sympy?
How do I show an equation like this:

I can show the left side using
display(binomial(n,k))

and the right side using
y= factorial(n)/(factorial(n-k) * factorial(k))
display(y)

but how do I show the equation?
Also, how do I make it show (n-k) instead of (-k+n)?

Make it into an Equality.
from sympy import init_session
init_session(quiet=True)

import sympy as smp
n, k = smp.symbols("n k")
eq = smp.Eq(smp.binomial(n, k), smp.factorial(n)/(smp.factorial(n-k) * smp.factorial(k)))
eq


The variable ordering in displayed result is determined internally by sympy (I believe it is alphabetical). There is a way to adjust this ordering by writing your own printer methods, but it is arguably more work than necessary. So, unless you have a specific reason why -k + n is an issue, I recommend leaving it as it is (mathematically, it is equivalent).

Can you explain what you mean by "the variable ordering is determined by sympy"? The symbolic variables you get out of symbols are ordered based on the input you give it, there is no hidden reordering: n, k = symbols("n, k") and k, n = symbols("k, n") do the same thing.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm referring to the display ordering, which is determined internally by sympy. Even though I wrote factorial(n-k), sympy will display it as -k + n because k comes before n in the alphabet.

Ah. It'd be nice to put that elaboration in the post.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added some clarification. What is the init_session stuff you added?

It lets you run the code in the REPL and get a properly formatted result printed to stdout, instead of Python printing the Eq(....) code (making the answer copy-paste-verifiable)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had run my code in a jupyter notebook and got the displayed result that I pasted in.

right, but Jupyter isn't plain Python (it auto-loads a bunch of graphical packages that plain Python doesn't) and the question wasn't tagged as Jupyter, so adding the session init means everyone can use this answer, not just folks using Jupyter =)
